# Can't change profile picture on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, profile-page, profile-picture

After dragging the picture I want into the area and clicking "Save Profile" at the bottom, I am prompted with the following message:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>
> - Display name may only be changed once every 30 days; you may change again on       Feb 5 at 17:01

Note that I have not changed my display name or any other name or setting in the process of doing so.

Comment: You *did* change your display name once. Make sure when you are trying to save your profile that you are using the correct/current display name and *only* changing your profile image.

Comment: If I did change my display name, it wouldn't have been to user7384984. So if there was an old name, how can i retrieve it?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. Your original, default, display name was user7384984. You changed it to your current display name, "Cuan Clifford." The system is telling you that you can't change it again during the same 30 day period.

Comment: I understand that but in my profile settings my display name is user7384984. I haven't changed that name so why does the message still appear when changing the picture only?

Comment: That's a separate issue. Your display name isn't "user7384984"; it's "Cuan Clifford". If you still see the former, then either you need to refresh your browser or you've found a completely different bug. Either way, submitting the form with that info will trigger the message you saw, for obvious reasons.